# Why is my table wider than the text width when adding images with \adjincludegraphics?

Tags: tables, tabularray

Could someone please explain why adding `\adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}` causes the table to become larger than the text width? Additionally, how can I ensure that the six columns, defined as `X[c,m]`, always have the same width, and the images are automatically rescaled to fit within their respective cells?  I would like to make my table the same width as the textwidth, with the last six columns being flexible and having equal widths. How can I achieve this? 
(I am using 8 columns because I need them for following rows)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{longtblr}[
]{
  colspec = { Q[c,t] Q[c] *{6}{X[c,m]} },
  width = \textwidth,
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
NO  & \SetCell[c=7]{c}  Some text &  & & & & & \\*
 1 &  \SetCell[c=7]{c} \textbf{Some text} &  &  &  &  &  & \\*
  &   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l]Q[c]Q[r]},rowspec={|Q[t]|Q[m]|Q[b]|}}
{Alpha \\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma \\
 Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta \\ Zeta} \\
 Eta & {Theta \\ Theta} & Iota \\
\end{tblr} & & &  \SetCell[c=3]{c}  \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l]Q[c]Q[r]},rowspec={|Q[t]|Q[m]|Q[b]|}}
{Alpha \\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma \\
 Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta \\ Zeta} \\
 Eta & {Theta \\ Theta} & Iota \\
\end{tblr} \\
% leave some space here
\\
 & &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ccccc},
       % vlines,
        hlines,
        hline{2,Z}={1pt},
        hline{1}={white},
        colsep=3pt,
        rowsep=3pt,
        row{1-Z}={font=\small},
        width=\linewidth
        }
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lcr},rowspec={|[2pt,green7]Q|[teal7]Q|[green7]Q|[3pt,teal7]}}
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{tblr}
\end{tblr} &  &  &  \SetCell[c=3]{c} \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}  \\
\end{longtblr}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is duplicate to two of your previous questions. You accept solution to the similar problem, Why then you not use them?

Comment: @Zarko your solution does not work well it creates spurious vertical space but I accepted it for the effort. 
and the solution of Jasper Habicht only  works with that particular example.

Comment: In both answer were stated, that that `tabularray` doesn't support well a way how you like to include image in table (due to bug or missed features) and that this can solve package author or some`tabularray` guru. You may inform him (on GitHub). Meanwhile see, if the hack in my answer below solve your problem sufficient satisfactory.

Comment: @Zarko I tried but I probably with more reputation would get him noticed than me.

Comment: And what about my answer?

Comment: @Zarko It seems like a trick. I don't know if I can make it work for my real table. Also what if the images are PDF? How would you set size then?

Comment: Sory, your comments make your question unclear. I don't know, what you like to have.

Comment: @Zarko you set this `width=44mm` which is the size of `example-image-a`. However, if the images are PDF format, how do you get the size to set them?

Comment: New problem, new question. ALl images, which inclusion is supired by `\includegraphics` or in your case with `\adjincludegraphics` can be scaled to prescribed width. Please read package documentation for details (supported graphic types).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question together with the comments made seems confusing. A clear and crisp question with all relevant boundary conditions or side effects should be formulated instead.

Answer (score 4):

The possible hack for your problem is to define absolute width of images. For example width:

```
\adjustboxset{width=44mm, valign=m}
```

MWE, a we bit redesigned, can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\adjustboxset{width=44mm, valign=m}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption},
  label = {tab:long+image}
                ]{colspec = {cQ[c,m] *{6}{X[c,m]} },
                  cell{1}{2} = {c=7}{},
                  cell{2}{2} = {c=7}{font=\bfseries},
                  colsep  = 3pt,
                  hlines, vlines,
                  rowsep  = 3pt,
                  rowhead = 2
                 }
NO  &   Some text 
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \\*
 1  &   Some text
        &   &   &   &   &   &   \\*
    &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c, m}
            \begin{tblr}{colsep  = 3pt,
                         colspec = {@{} *{3}{Q[c, m]} @{}},
                  hline{1,Z} = {2pt, fg=teal},
                         hline{2-Y} = {fg=teal}
                         }
            {Alpha\\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma  \\ 
            Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta\\ Zeta} \\
            Eta   & {Theta\\ Theta} & Iota  \\
            \end{tblr}
            &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c,m}
                        \begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
                                     colspec = { @{} *{3}{Q[c, m]}  @{}},
                                     hline{1,Z} = {2pt, fg=teal},
                                     hline{2-Y} = {fg=teal}
                         }
                        {Alpha\\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma  \\
                        Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta\\ Zeta} \\
                        Eta   & {Theta\\ Theta} & Iota  \\
                        \end{tblr}
                        &   &   \\*
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\*
    &   {Normalised\\ Coefficient}
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c, m}
            \begin{tblr}{colsep = 3pt,
                         colspec = { @{} *{3}{Q[c, m]}  @{}},
                         hline{1,Z} = {2pt, fg=teal},
                         hline{2-Y} = {fg=teal}
                         }
            {Alpha\\ Alpha} & Beta & Gamma  \\
            Delta & Epsilon & {Zeta\\ Zeta} \\
            Eta   & {Theta\\ Theta} & Iota  \\
            \end{tblr}
            &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} 
                        \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a} 
                        &   &   \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]